# Thingsboard Widgets Library Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, iot, thingsboard

I'm trying to make a custom widget on Thingsboard that would change the text when it's pressed. Like this:
[Custom Widget creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkvJn.png)

But it's not working at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't post your code in images. Post it as code so we can copy it. Please don't link to external images. Insert images directly into your post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the official widgets development guide?

There are some examples that use click-events

https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#static-widget

Thingsboard uses AngularJS, so you can bind click-handlers to elements with the `ng-click` attribute like this:

```
<p id="text" ng-click="changeText()">Text</p>
```

To make this work you will need to create that click-handler in the widget's scope. The perfect place to do this is the `onInit()` method of the widget.

```
self.onInit = function() {
    self.ctx.$scope.changeText = function() {
        // change your text here
    };
};
```